# App Store Connect metrics: What is "Active Devices" and "Active Last 30 Days"?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, analytics

The tooltip next to "Active Devices" and "Active Last 30 Days" says

> The total number of devices with at least one **session** during the
>   selected period

and

> The total number of devices with at least one **session** within 30 days of the selected day" >respectively.

Next to those, it defines another metric called "Sessions" as

> The number of times the app has been used for at least two seconds.

What does apple mean by a "device with at least one **session** during the selected period"? Is it referring to a device that was merely booted, or a device on which our app was launched during the selected period? I haven't been able to find any clarification on that.

On google play connect "Active devices" refers to devices that were active (no matter whether the app was fired during that period).

Answer (score 1):

Before we dive deeper you must understand what session is. Definition of session for Apple App Analytics is:

> The number of times the app has been used for at least two seconds. If the app is in the background and is later used again, that counts as another session.

Then we can define what period is:

> a length or portion of time.

From this we can conclude that *Active Devices* gives you information about devices that was running you application at least once and for at least two seconds in that given period. For example if you select dates from 19 July 2018 to 19 July 2019(this is your period), you will get number of devices that was running your app at least **once** and for at least **two seconds** in that given period.

Same goes for *Active Last 30 Days*, only that now your period is last 30 days.

Resources:

- [Apple App Analytics 101 (updated)](https://medium.com/appmanager/apple-app-analytics-101-93f399b41ff4)
- [App Store Connect Help](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain! Your assumption is that apple uses the word session in both phrases (definition of an "active device" and definition of a "session") with the same meaning: an app session. And you are probably correct. I came across a very different definition of an Active Device for google play however, and that got me wondering whether Apple was using the word "session" loosly: For google a "device is active" as long as the app is installed; no app session is required within any period. I was hoping to find some documentation that clarifies the point.

Comment: Don’t really know what you want to explain to me but here is clear explanation what session mean in Apple App Analytics: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/itc14b94d665